# Population Transition Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given a matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0.7 & 0.2\\ 
3 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

which is said to be the transition matrix for a fish population. There is a 70% adult survival rate and a 20% survival rate for young fish. Adult fish produce on average 3 young fish per year.

The dominant eigenvalue is 1.2 and so the population grows at an asymptotic rate of 20% per year. Suppose we decide to allow fishing and allow a certain yearly fraction $f$ of adult fish to be caught. Then we have

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0.7 - f & 0.2\\ 
3 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

If we pick $f$ very small the population will still grow. If we pick $f$ too large the population will die off. We want to pick $f$ just right so that the population will be stable.

> (a) What does this stability condition mean in terms of the largest eigenvalue of $A$?

The dominant eigenvalue should be $1$.

> (b) What does $f$ have to be in order for this to happen?

I wanted $1$ to be an eigenvalue, so I took

$$\begin{vmatrix}
0.4 - f -1 & 0.2\\ 
3 & -1
\end{vmatrix}$$

and solved for $f$. This gave me $f = 0.3$.

> (c) For this value of $f$, find the eigen values and eigenvectors of $A$.

I found eigenvalues $\lambda = 1$ and $\lambda = -0.6$.

> If there are initially no fish in the lake, and we wish to stock it with adult fish so that the total number of fish is 10000 when it hits the stable level (counting adult and young fish together), how many adult fish should we introduce into the lake?

I am stuck on this part. Do I need something like:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}
A^n
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\ 
b
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $a+b = 10000$? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: (c) asked for the eigenvalues *and* the eigenvectors; you found the former, but not the latter. You need an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $1$, with components adding to $10,000$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key idea is that if you have two distinct eigenvalues, then you have a basis of eigenvectors. In other word if you have found two eigenvectors (for the two eigenvalues), say $x$ and $y$, then you can write your initial configuration (uniquely) as a vector of the form
$$\alpha x+\beta y$$
Then as time progresses your constelation will be
$$A^n(\alpha x+\beta y)=\alpha A^nx+\beta A^ny=\alpha x+\beta(-0.6)^ny$$
And if we pass to the limit, i.e. let $n$ go to $\infty$, we get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}A^n(\alpha x+\beta y)=\alpha x$$.

Now you want the sum of the components of $\alpha x$ to be $10000$ and the second entry of $\alpha x+\beta y$ to be $0$ (no young fish). Since you know $x$ and $y$ you can solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Edit: In reality you will obviously only have an integer number of fish. So the vector $\beta(-0.6)^ny$ has to be rounded down. For the exercise this is irrelevant though. You will have less than one fish in this term after *finitely* many steps.